# how to read a password protected zip file in c#

Tags: c#, passwords, zip

suggest me to read password protected zip file using c#

Answer (score 3):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is a free open-source library for working with zip files. It supports password protected files so it should be just what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Following code shows how to decompress a password protected ZIP archive using our [Rebex ZIP component](http://www.rebex.net/zip.net/).

```
// open a ZIP archive 
using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(@"C:\archive.zip", ArchiveOpenMode.Open))
{
    // set the Password first 
    zip.Password = "PASSword#123";

    // extract whole ZIP content 
    zip.ExtractAll(@"C:\Data");
}
```

Free [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) might a be viable alternative (if you don't mind that it's licensed under LGPL).