# How to extract passowrd protected ZIP file using shell32 in c#?

Tags: c#, zip, runtime-error, shell32.dll

I have written some code in C#, however, it fails if my ZIP file is password protected otherwise extracts the file if there is no password protection.

```
Shell32.ShellClass sc = new Shell32.ShellClass();            
Shell32.Folder SrcFlder = sc.NameSpace("c:\\test1.zip");
Shell32.Folder DestFlder = sc.NameSpace("c:\\test");
Shell32.FolderItems items = SrcFlder.Items();
DestFlder.CopyHere(items,20);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is a free open-source library for working with zip files. It supports password protected files so it should be just what you are after.

Please visit the post
[how to read a password protected zip file in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998168/how-to-read-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-c-sharp)